# How to resolve conflict in Devise mass assign errors

Tags: ruby, devise

I have an application that was running just fine using Devise for authentication.  I added CanCan and I am now having issues with Devise.  Given the standard "encrypted_password" and "password_confirmation" attributes if they are not specified as attr_accessible then when the controller tries to do:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

I get the standard MassAssignment error.  But if I add them to the attr_accessible list I can then create the user but it will then fail on password validation since the attr_accessible does not let Devise encrypt the password.  I suspect the issue is something in my routes since I have both:

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'secure'
resources :users
```

The resources :users is there so that the admin and use standard CRUD type operations to manage CanCan.

Not sure if more detail is needed but this sounds like a core issue that I am stubbing my toe on.

Thank you

Comment: What does your Ability class look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  Someone had changed the model's attr_accessible list to have encrypted_password not password.  Devise is looking for the password in the parameters and then creates the encrypted_password for the model.

Another newbeee programmer has learned a lesson :)  So did I, double check changes made by newbes!

Thankyou